# 'onBeforePerformAction' alternative for craft 2.4.0?

Tags: plugin-development

Is there an alternate event for `onBeforePerformAction`? I want to handle an `onDeleteEntry`, but apparently that doesn't work on a bulk delete (deleting from the check boxes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. That's why `onBeforePerformAction` was introduced in [2.5](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2750).

I would **highly** recommend that you update Craft to the latest version ([2.6.2944](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2944)). In addition to all of the cool features that you are missing out on, there was also a **critical security update** released in [2.6.2791](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2791). Without that update, you may be leaving sensitive data exposed.